# How to use iOSOpdenDev's XPC Template

Tags: ios, jailbreak

When I create an iOS daemon project with **iOSOpenDev XPC Template**, there has about 20 errors. i had symlink the xpc.h file.
[image: the xcode error screenshot]

Can anyone help me to solve it,or has there any available XPC template?

Answer (score 0):

That just means you pretty much forgot to either:

```
close off a closure i.e.:

void whatever(void){ ...
     /* code here*/
```

no close bracer `}`

or you forgot to terminate an expression with `;`

When you compile, you'll get a lot of errors "AFTER" where this error happens, so where you first see it happening, is where the issue usually is.

IN your case it won't be easy as it seems to have happened around/near an included symbol.

When you're in Xcode itelf, at the top left, (above the file and project navigator) is the `issue navigator`. This can be pretty accurate in taking you to the issue as it lies.

What you're looking for in Xcode is this:

[image]

After you click on the tab I highlight first, any symbol you click on after that (as I showed just below that), will most of the time steer Xcode to were the issue is.

If it doesn't, the it's usually an external library, missing library, or reference to code that is no longer there (i.e. when Apple change their Application API's)

Hope this helps!